# How do I query custom data structure with Tellor? (e.g. my own API)

Tags: oracles, data-feeds, tellor

I have a program for an NFT market index that I host through an API, just wanted some way to put it on-chain in a way that made sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tellor can definitely do it for you.  Caveat, you may just want to define the actual data to put on-chain and open source the calculation method.  The problem with self-hosted API’s is that they can go down and then the Tellor reporters have nothing to query.

But assuming you know how to integrate the solidity piece, there’s three more pieces you have to do.

- Finalize [a dataSpec](https://github.com/tellor-io/dataSpecs) (you should be on your way if you made an issue in github in the first step)
- [Tip it on a testnet](https://docs.tellor.io/tellor/integration/requesting-paying-for-data)

  This puts a bounty up for the next person who submits the value on-chain.  This will make it real.  Once someone submits it, be sure to check that it’s what you want and your contract works!
- Ping the reporters on discord to get support.

For a full walkthrough, you can check out this article:  https://tellor.io/blog/how-to-query-custom-data-with-tellor/